# why my playClick and stopClick button is never used?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

this is my issues, so my button handler on activity stated my method was never used but i'm already create the button on XML

activity：

[image]

XML：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file change the `tools:context` in the root `LinearLayout` to the path of your Activity because this data is being used to bind the `onClick` action

As I can tell from the screenshots it should be changed to

```xml
tools:context=".LanderActivity"
```

Comment: i've changed tools:context into tools:context=".LanderActivity" but still the same